# Disprove $ f\mid e^2, e\gcd(e,f),\gcd(e,f)^2\Rightarrow f\mid e\ $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

(This has been cross-posted from [a now-deleted MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415285), per advice from [Neil Strickland](https://mathoverflow.net/users/10366).)

Suppose we have **natural numbers** $E$ and $F$ such that all of
$$G = \frac{\bigg(\gcd(E,F)\bigg)^2}{F}$$
$$H = \frac{E^2}{F}$$
$$I = \bigg(\frac{E}{F}\bigg)\cdot\gcd(E,F)$$
and
$$J = \frac{E}{\gcd(E,F)}$$
are also natural numbers.

Here are my questions:

> Is it possible to ask the theorem prover called **Lean** whether it follows from these combined premises that $F$ divides $E$?  If so, what is **Lean**'s answer?

(**Caveat**: I know that **Lean** is open source, however, I have not yet gotten down to studying it in detail, so any help is appreciated.)

Comment: By basic gcd arithmetic $\,f \mid e^2\iff f\mid e(e,f)\iff f\mid (e,f)^2$.

Therefore your question is equivalent to: does $\,f\mid e^2\Rightarrow f\mid e\,?$ which of course has obvious counterexamples, e.g. $\,f = e^2\,$ for $|e|> 1,\, $ e..g $\,e = 2,3\,$ as you noted. **Those are dupes** so you should delete it to save us the effort in doing so.

Comment: @BillDubuque:  Pardon me, but before you vote to close it as a duplicate, is it indeed an **exact duplicate** of a previous question?

Comment: Said gcd inferences and counterexamples are all discussed here numerous times. There is no need to find the *exact* same question to close it as a dupe (else the site would be swamped with dupe Q&As)

Comment: @BillDubuque:  But this question is interesting (at least to me) in its own right.  I highly suggest you post your first comment as an answer, instead of closing this question as a duplicate.  Agreed?  (For one, **it is not at all obvious to me** how you got those biconditionals.)

Comment: As said, by the dupe $\ f\mid e\cdot e\iff f\mid e(e,f)\iff f\mid (e,f)(e,f)\ $ There are also many dupes showing counterexcamples to $\,f\mid e^2 \Rightarrow f\mid e\ $ which can be found e.g. using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/). Please strive not to post  questions that are dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: In case it is not clear note that iterating the linked General Euclid's Lemma implies that in any divisibility of the form $\,a\mid b_1\cdots b_k\,$ we can by replace any (or all) of the $\,\color{#c00}{b_i}\,$ by $\,\color{#c00}{(a,b_i)}\,$ without changing the truth of the divisibility, i.e. such replacements yield an *equivalent* divisibility statement.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments from Neil Strickland in MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415285/can-the-following-conjecture-be-checked-using-the-theorem-prover-called-lean?noredirect=1#comment1065114_415285) and [there](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415285/can-the-following-conjecture-be-checked-using-the-theorem-prover-called-lean?noredirect=1#comment1065117_415285):

- The case $(E,F)=(2,4)$ is a counterexample.
- The case $(E,F)=(3,9)$ is also a counterexample.

Neil also advised that **Lean** is mostly for checking proofs, it is not very good at finding them.